# R-Package httr can be used, but I'm told that it is not available when building my own package which uses httr

Tags: r, httr

I'm trying to create my first package in R. When I run "Check package" in RStudio, I get the following error message:

```
==> devtools::check(document = FALSE)

-- Building ------------------------------------------ w.api.r --
Setting env vars:
* CFLAGS    : -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
* CXXFLAGS  : -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
* CXX11FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
-----------------------------------------------------------------
v  checking for file 'C:\Users\einaf\Downloads\w.api.r/DESCRIPTION' (670ms)
-  preparing 'w.api.r':
v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (360ms)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Omitted 'LazyData' from DESCRIPTION
-  building 'w.api.r_0.1.0.tar.gz'
   
-- Checking ------------------------------------------ w.api.r --
Setting env vars:
* _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_REMOTE_: FALSE
* _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_       : FALSE
* _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_      : FALSE
* NOT_CRAN                      : true
-- R CMD check -----------------------------------------------------------------
-  using log directory 'C:/Users/einaf/Downloads/w.api.r.Rcheck' (724ms)
-  using R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
-  using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
-  using session charset: ISO8859-1
-  using options '--no-manual --as-cran'
v  checking for file 'w.api.r/DESCRIPTION' ... 
-  checking extension type ... Package
-  this is package 'w.api.r' version '0.1.0'
-  package encoding: UTF-8
v  checking package namespace information
v  checking package dependencies (4.6s)
v  checking if this is a source package ...
v  checking if there is a namespace
v  checking for executable files (354ms)
v  checking for hidden files and directories ...
v  checking for portable file names ... 
v  checking serialization versions
E  checking whether package 'w.api.r' can be installed (1.4s)
   Installation failed.
   See 'C:/Users/einaf/Downloads/w.api.r.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.
   
   See
     'C:/Users/einaf/Downloads/w.api.r.Rcheck/00check.log'
   for details.
   
-- R CMD check results -------------------------------------- w.api.r 0.1.0 ----
Duration: 7.3s

> checking whether package 'w.api.r' can be installed ... ERROR
  See below...

-- Install failure -------------------------------------------------------------

* installing *source* package 'w.api.r' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in library(httr) : es gibt kein Paket namens 'httr'
Fehler: kann R Programmkode in Paket 'w.api.r' nicht laden
Ausführung angehalten
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'w.api.r'
* removing 'C:/Users/einaf/Downloads/w.api.r.Rcheck/w.api.r'

1 error x | 0 warnings v | 0 notes v
Fehler: R CMD check found ERRORs
Ausführung angehalten

Exited with status 1.
```

I'm sorry that parts of it are in German. The translation is, that there is no package "httr" and that checking my own package was stopped.

What I don't understand is, that I can successfully use `library(httr)` in the console and that I successfully can use the package httr after that while working on my package. I have no idea how to solve this issue.

What I have already tried:

- restarting RStudio
- updating R
- updating RStudio
- reinstalling httr
- reinstalling httr with `install.packages("httr", type = "binary")`
- reinstalling httr with `install.packages("httr", dependencies = TRUE)`
- rebuilding my package

I am very happy about any helpful suggestions and want to thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know where exactly you are using `httr` in your package? Did you include it in your package DESCRIPTION file? Do you actually `library(httr)` in your package code? Because it shouldn't be there. We really need some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to see what's going on to help futher.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can understand that you need an example, but I haven't provided an reproducible example because I didn't know how to do it, because my package is about accessing an API, and any example includes my private login data, which I can't provide. Sorry, I didn't know how to make an example without that data.
But you've managed to solve the problem anyway! My mistake was that I forgot to include httr in my package description file. `usethis::use_package("httr")` solved the problem. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me! :)